# Spring Security: как поменять HTTP Status для response?

Tags: java, spring-security

При неудачной авторизации мне необходимо отдавать обратно статус 401. Поскольку у нас в проекте используется `Spring Security`, то и настройка авторизации настраивается через него:

```
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatcher(ADMIN_MATCHERS)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHERS)
                    .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter(USERNAME)
                    .passwordParameter(PASSWORD)
                    .loginPage(ADMIN_LOGIN)
                    .permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/login/auth")
                    .failureHandler(customAuthFailureHandler)
                    .successHandler(successHandler())
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/admin/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(ADMIN_LOGIN)
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage(ADMIN_LOGIN)
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .httpBasic();
```

Для обработки ошибки авторизации я, как мы видим, использовал `failureHandler()`.

И написал кастомный обработчик:

```
@Component("customAuthFailureHandler")
public class CustomAuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    private static final String ADMIN_LOGIN = "/admin/login";
    private static final Integer STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
    private static final String RESPONSE_CODE_KEY = "Response-Code";
    private static final String RESPONSE_BAD_CREDENTIALS = "bad-credentials";

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.addHeader(RESPONSE_CODE_KEY, RESPONSE_BAD_CREDENTIALS);
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, ADMIN_LOGIN);
    }
}
```

Header пересылается без проблем, но вместо статуса 401 ответом приходит 302. То есть, определённый мной статус где-то затирается. Возможно, не нужно использовать `sendRedirect`?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, рабочее решение в рамках имеющегося кода.

Comment: [Здесь](https://github.com/brant-hwang/spring-boot-social-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/axisj/examples/spring/social/security/CustomLoginFailureHandler.java) есть пример имплементации, так же можете почитать Spring REST (Apress), там есть примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, выяснилось, что можно сделать или переадресацию с, допустим, хэдерами, но без `HttpStatus`, или добавить `HttpStatus`, но без переадресации. Так, чтоб был и статус, и переадресация, силами Spring Security сделать нельзя.

Я решил задачу следующим образом: создал другую jsp и поменял в настройках строчку

```
.failureHandler(customAuthFailureHandler)
```

на

```
.failureUrl(ADMIN_LOGIN_FAILED)
```

То же самое можно сделать и силами хэндлера.